# Copy the row in pandas from the nearest year

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say that I have the following datasets.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'name': ['a', 'a', 'a'], 'year': [2000, 2001, 2002], 'value': [10, 17, 22] }
data_frame  = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
data_frame

d1 = {'name': ['a', 'a', 'a'], 'year': [2001, 2002, 2003], 'value': [10, 17, 22] }
data_frame1  = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
data_frame1

d2 = {'name': ['a', 'a', 'a'], 'year': [2000, 2002, 2003], 'value': [10, 17, 22] }
data_frame2  = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
data_frame2
```

What I want to do is following:

1. In `data_frame`, I miss observations for 2003, hence I want to copy the row which contains 2002 (the earliest available year) `(data_frame[data_frame['year']==2002])` append it to my `data_frame` and replace 2002 with 2003. Rest stays the same.
2. In `data_frame1`, I miss observations for 2000, I want to do the same as in 1, but in that case, I want to use the row which contains the year 2001.
3. As for the `data_frame2`, I do not have observations for 2001. Here I want to use the earliest year, e.i. 2000.

Is there any way that I can do this, without inspecting each data frame separately, but instead write some general function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with all years with parameter `method='nearest'`, but for `data_frame2` is used next year:

```
dfs = [data_frame,data_frame1, data_frame2]

for df in dfs:
    df = df.set_index('year').reindex(range(2000, 2004), method='nearest')
    print (df)
         name  value
    year            
    2000    a     10
    2001    a     17
    2002    a     22
    2003    a     22
         name  value
    year            
    2000    a     10
    2001    a     10
    2002    a     17
    2003    a     22
         name  value
    year            
    2000    a     10
    2001    a     17
    2002    a     17
    2003    a     22
```

If need previous year if exist, last replace next year use:

```
for df in dfs:
    df = df.set_index('year').reindex(range(2000, 2004), method='ffill').bfill()
    print (df)
         name  value
    year            
    2000    a     10
    2001    a     17
    2002    a     22
    2003    a     22
         name  value
    year            
    2000    a   10.0
    2001    a   10.0
    2002    a   17.0
    2003    a   22.0
         name  value
    year            
    2000    a     10
    2001    a     10
    2002    a     17
    2003    a     22
```

Solution per groups:

```
for df in dfs:
    df = (df.set_index('year').groupby('name', group_keys=False)
            .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(range(2000, 2004), method='ffill').bfill()))
    print (df)
         name  value
    year            
    2000    a     10
    2001    a     17
    2002    a     22
    2003    a     22
         name  value
    year            
    2000    a   10.0
    2001    a   10.0
    2002    a   17.0
    2003    a   22.0
         name  value
    year            
    2000    a     10
    2001    a     10
    2002    a     17
    2003    a     22
```